# Having an issue escaping an ampersand in a link when calling mail utility in MacOs

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, subprocess, escaping

So I have some automation code written in Python that populates an email template string, one being a link to a Splunk query that contains the character `&`. Once I have populated the email, I take the args passed in to create a cmdline to call the subprocess library like so:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=inout, stdout=inout,
                                stderr=inout, close_fds=closefds,
                                preexec_fn=setsid, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Now `cmdline` is a list that contains the following:

```
['open', "mailto:comman_separated_emails?cc=dummy_email@gmail.com&subject=My subject&body=Some 
text with the following problem link: 
https://splunk-link.com:443/app/my_app/@go?dispatch_view=alert&s=%2FservicesNS%2Fnobody%2Fapigateway-prod%2Fsaved%2Fsearches%2FAPI%2520Gateway%2520Credential%2520Security%2520Violation%253A%2520Auth%2520Header%2520on%2520HTTP%2520%2528Non%2520SSL%2529%2520-%2520Daily"]
```

Every time my default mail provider opens up, Outlook in this case, the message gets cut off right at the `&` in the link.

I have tried to put the link in double and single quotes, escaped with `\&\` and `^&`, but still no luck.

Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance.

-Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is the separator between parameters in the URL. You need to encode it as `%26`.

You can use `urllib.parse.quote()` to encode all the characters that need to be encoded.

```
quoted_link = urllib.parse.quote('https://splunk-link.com:443/app/my_app/@go?dispatch_view=alert&s=%2FservicesNS%2Fnobody%2Fapigateway-prod%2Fsaved%2Fsearches%2FAPI%2520Gateway%2520Credential%2520Security%2520Violation%253A%2520Auth%2520Header%2520on%2520HTTP%2520%2528Non%2520SSL%2529%2520-%2520Daily')
cmdline = ["open", f"""mailto:comman_separated_emails?cc=dummy_email@gmail.com&subject=My subject&body=Some 
text with the following problem link: 
{quoted_link}"""]
```

Comment: Hi Barmar. Thanks for your help! I am able to get the full string through now to a new email pop up, but when I click on the link, it doesn't work because the ampersand is missing: ```urllib.parse.quote(alert_location, safe='/:?=@%')```. I replace the %26 with & and the link works. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Make sure you're only quoting the embedded link, not the whole URL. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's what I did: ```'alert_location': urllib.parse.quote(alert_location, safe='/:?=@%')``` then ```body = EMAIL_TEMPLATE.format(**context)```. The browser is not liking the ```%26``` since it's breaking the link when I click on it. ```context``` is just a dict that fills in all the info inside ```EMAIL_TEMPLATE```.

Comment: This is the url that is encoded that does not work: ```https%3A//ip.scheduled.splunk.com%3A443/app/myapp/%40go%3Fdispatch_view%3Dalert%26s%3D%252FservicesNS%252Fnobody%252Fapigateway-prod%252Fsaved%252Fsearches%252FAPI%252520Gateway%252520Credential%252520Security%252520Violation%25253A%252520Auth%252520Header%252520on%252520HTTP%252520%252528Non%252520SSL%252529%252520-%252520Daily```

Comment: maybe the problem is that you encoded other characters in that URL already. You should let `urllib.parse.quote` do all the encoding.

Comment: I think you're right. The url looks to be encoded by the time my script does the encoding again. Looking further into it.